# Cause of cmake build error finding g++.exe files using Windows and Mingw (Libtorch Installation)?

Tags: c++, cmake, pytorch, g++, libtorch

Following the guidelines found on https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/installing.html, I am trying to install Libtorch. I am on Windows and using MinGW to get the compiler. I followed the instructions as well as I can, with the exception of downloading an extracting the library manually, and skipping the if(MSVS) step in the CMakeFiles since I am not using it. I also added Torch_DIR to the path to make the first step work. The code is below, the error occuring when I try to build.

```
#No obvious errors here to me
C:\...\example-app\build>cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\...\libtorch ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Found Torch: C:/.../torch.lib
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/.../build

#The build doesnt work
C:\...\example-app\build>cmake --build . --config Release
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/example-app.dir/example-app.cpp.obj
g++.exe: error: /EHsc: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: /DNOMINMAX: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: /wd4267: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: /wd4251: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: /wd4522: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: /wd4838: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: /wd4305: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: /wd4244: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: /wd4190: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: /wd4101: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: /wd4996: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: /wd4275: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: /bigobj: No such file or directory
CMakeFiles\example-app.dir\build.make:75: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/example-app.dir/example-app.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/example-app.dir/example-app.cpp.obj] Error 1
```

Comment: Building with mingw is not officially supported. https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/24460. You should use MSVC.

Comment: `/EHsc ... /DNOMINMAX ... /wd4267 ... and so on ` - this looks like a compiler definitions for MSVC, not MinGW. Check out compiler flags

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is PyTorch failing to build with MinGW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76153651/why-is-pytorch-failing-to-build-with-mingw)